# JOOQ store() does not return ResultSet

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-insert, jooq

Following [this](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/simple-crud/) I try to create a new Student Record, assign it some Values and store it to the Database.

```
DSLContext ctx = ...

StudentRecord s = ctx.newRecord(Student.STUDENT);
    s.setFirstname("Nicolas");
    s.setLastname("Nox");
    s.setGender("M");
    s.setYearOfBirth((short) 1990);
    s.store(); <-- ERROR
```

**EDIT 1:**
The same goes for `insert()`
**End of Edit 1**
**EDIT 2:**
The Student Table contains nothing more than the four values shown above. The Model is autogenerated and select worked so far.
**End of Edit 2**

**Edit 3:**
As asked here the Table Definition for Student and the dependency of the JDBC Driver.

```
create table [LECTURE_DB].[dbo].[STUDENT](
[ID] int identity(1, 1) not null,
[FIRSTNAME] nvarchar(20) not null,
[LASTNAME] nvarchar(20) not null,
[YEAR_OF_BIRTH] smallint null,
[GENDER] nvarchar(1) null,
constraint [PK__STUDENT__3214EC277F60ED59]
  primary key ([ID]),
  constraint [STUDENT_NAME_IDX]
  unique (
    [LASTNAME], 
    [FIRSTNAME]
  )
)

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

**End of Edit 3**

This does insert a Value into the Database but the Record is not  correctly updated.
The following Error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [declare @result table ([ID] int); insert 
into [LECTURE_DB].[dbo].[STUDENT] ([FIRSTNAME], [LASTNAME], [YEAR_OF_BIRTH], [GENDER]) output 
[inserted].[ID] into @result values (?, ?, ?, ?); select [r].[ID] from @result [r];]; The statement did not return a result set.
at org.jooq_3.12.1.SQLSERVER2014.debug(Unknown Source)
at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2717)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:755)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:383)
at org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl.storeInsert0(TableRecordImpl.java:206)
at org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl$1.operate(TableRecordImpl.java:177)
at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:130)
at org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl.storeInsert(TableRecordImpl.java:173)
at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.store0(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:196)
at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl$1.operate(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:136)
at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:130)
at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.store(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:132)
at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.store(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:124)
at de.esteam.lecturedb.jooq.LectureDBSetup.insertInitialData(LectureDBSetup.java:49)
at de.esteam.lecturedb.jooq.LectureDBAnalysis.<init>(LectureDBAnalysis.java:77)
at de.esteam.lecturedb.jooq.LectureDBAnalysis.<clinit>(LectureDBAnalysis.java:44)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set. at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:464)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:405)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:208)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:183)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:317)
at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:94)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.executeReturningQuery(AbstractDMLQuery.java:1137)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.execute(AbstractDMLQuery.java:935)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:369)
... 12 more
```

stating the missing ResultSet from the Database to update the ID in my Application.

I kinda need the Records and the IDs since I need to insert many values with foreign keys.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted more of your code. What does the StudentRecord class look like? What does  the failing JOOQ code look like? What does the database table look like?

Comment: Would you mind adding your JDBC driver version to your question?

Comment: Also: A table definition (`CREATE TABLE ...`) would be very helpful

Comment: Updated in Edit 3. Hope this helps. @LukasEder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ using SQL Server `OUTPUT` to fetch result data from DML statements is a new feature from jOOQ 3.12: [#4498](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4498). It has a few known issues in version 3.12.2, including:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8917

Yours was not known yet. I'll update my answer once I know more about it.

A workaround could be to turn off generating the `OUTPUT` clause in SQL Server, which should still work for single-row DML statements like yours. Set your [`Settings.renderOutputForSQLServerReturningClause`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#renderOutputForSQLServerReturningClause) flag to `false`